.py-script only runs via terminal and not with the "run"-button of Pycharm
I created a new Python project in PyCharm using a virtual environment. This is my first time using virtual environments, and I am still a beginner with Python and PyCharm. For some reason, Python can't find any packages anymore, even though I am certain that I installed scikit-learn within the virtual environment.
When using the terminal, everything works perfectly as long as I activate the virtual environment with source .../venv/Scripts/activate. If I deactivate the virtual environment with deactivate, the packages are no longer found, which is expected behavior. Running pip list shows scikit-learn only when the virtual environment is activated.
In PyCharm, when I go to Settings > Python Interpreter, the virtual environment interpreter is selected (...\venv\Scripts\python.exe). However, no packages are listed there.
What did I do wrong, and how can I fix this issue?
I searched online for similar problems and checked all the settings described above.

This question is similar to: How to select Python version in PyCharm?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't want to change the Python version, it is the same version, just a virtual environment.

I had a similar problem few years ago. Try with these steps. I followed them all, step by step, and it worked for me, I hope I can be useful:
First of all, make sure that PyCharm is selected in the virtual enviroment, it may seem obvious but you always want to rule that one out. To do this, go to File, then Settings. (if you're on Windows). Then, go to Project > (your project) > Python Interpreter.
If that didn't work, you wanna make sure to synchronize the virtual enviroment packages. To do that, in the same Python Interpreter settings window, click on the circular arrow icon (refresh icon) next to the interpreter dropdown to refresh the list of packages installed.
If that didn't work too, try checking that te VE is set as the project interpreter (right click on your project root in the Project Tool and press F4 or Open module settings.
At this point, it did work for me. However, if it still doesn't work, try also checking pycharm terminal settings (go to file > settings > tools > terminal and set the Shell path to the virtual environment activation script); or if nothing works, try re-creating the VE and consider posting your pycharm logs.
Hope this helps!
